# `className` did not match. Server:

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am using NextJS getServerSideProps to fetch data and the page is rendering correctly with the data. So this works fine except when rendering a dynamic classname property on a html element I am getting the following error:

```
Prop `className` did not match. Server: "" Client: "dark"
```

when rendering the following component:

```
function Header(props: { darkMode: boolean }) {
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(props.darkMode);
  
  return (
      <div className={(darkMode ? "dark" : "")}></div>   
  );
 }
 export default Header;
```

When debugging I can see that darkMode is true but the div element is still rendered without the className, assuming it's due to the error descriped above.

I am actually using MaterialUI although this element is not an materialUI element.

I have specified .bablerc like this:

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": [["styled-components", { "ssr": true }]]
}
```

Any idea why I am getting this error?

Comment: The issue happens because `darkMode` value differs in the server and client. Whatever's changing that value should happen inside a `useEffect`.

Comment: It seems others have the same issue https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/7322#issuecomment-723730380. some of them solved by renaming the .babelrc file. fwiw it's an antipattern to create state from props

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem like the issue is the same as the one mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63928337/css-style-is-not-correctly-being-applied-when-conditional-render-in-react/63974991#63974991). If that's the case, I have posted the answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63974991/2816062)

The `className` mismatch is related to how React syncs up the DOM node after a page is server-side rendered. Since React will only patch/sync the text context for the node and `className` is an attribute. A warning is triggered.

**Reference**

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11128#issuecomment-334882514